# Assigning cards from decks to hands

Tags: c, arrays

I have a card game assignment, and I'm confused on how to properly deal the user and the computer 5 cards from the deck using a call by reference. Here is the requirement for the function:this function removes the top card from the deck and returns it to the calling function, while shifting the rest of the deck up one card. Note that the size of the deck must be decremented to reflect the loss of one card (This should be done using Call by Reference).

And here is my current code for the function, but I don't think it's right. Please don't be overly technical, I'm a noob. Thanks.

```
int popCard(int *size, int deck[])
{
    int user[5];
    int comp[5];
    int i,j;
    for(j=0; j<=5; j++)
    {
        for(i=51; i>=47; i--)
        {
            user[j]=i;
        }
        for(i=46; i>=42; i--)
        {
            comp[j]=i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think you should be using `size` inside the function, instead of hard-coding `51` and `46` in your loops?

Comment: The variable `user` is local to the function, and so won't exist after it returns. If you want a function to deal a card from a deck to a user, you have to create both outside.

Comment: Change `j<=5` to `j<5`.

Comment: Barmar, it makes it easier for me to decrement the number of times I wish.

Comment: Lee, are you saying I should declare them globally?  
barak, thanks.

Comment: Start simple.  How would you return the first card from the deck, without even bothering to shift the rest of the cards?  Because right now your function isn't even returning anything.  Once you figure that out, tackle the next step.  And by the way, throw out all of your current code first.  The requirement says to deal one card and you are trying to deal 5 cards, which is way more complicated than what you should be doing.

Comment: Thanks, I believe the card would be returned using pointers? about the five cards, the assignment does require five cards, but the description given is just a description on what needs to happen.

Comment: Your own question says *"this function removes the top card from the deck and returns it to the calling function"*. So the 2 five-card hands are not dealt inside the function. The card is returned as the function value, and I suggest `-1` if there are no cards in the deck.

Comment: No, I don't necessarilt mean globals--unless that happens to be the best design for your program.  You just can't create and then destroy users inside a function of decks.

Answer (score 0):

A function in C can change the outside world in three ways:

1. Modify a global variable (yuck. avoid this.)
2. Return a value (yea! the function accomplished something...here it is)
3. Modify a value passed as a pointer.

So, let's say you have a "deck" object of some kind, and a "hand" object of some kind, and you want to deal a card. You *could* write a function that takes a pointer to both a deck and a hand and updates both:

```
void deal(Deck *deck, Hand *hand);
```

But probably a better design is one deck function and one hand function (assuming cards are `int`s, which they ought to be).

```
int dealfrom(Deck *deck);
void dealTo(Hand *hand, int card);
```

Then just

```
dealTo(h, dealFrom(d));
```

`Deck` and `Hand` should be structures that have an array of cards and a current size (and maybe a capacity, and other things as needed).